# Overlapping Grouping in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a dataset with some numbers for each month.
For example:

1/1/2009   param1 param2

2/1/2009   param1 param2

3/1/2009   param1 param2

What I need is to show 4 lines of summary:

1. last 6 months
2. this year (last 12 months)
3. last year (12 to 24 months ago)
4. total

I was thinking of adding a parameter for each record that assings each record to a specific time frame (6 months ago, 12 months ago, etc.). But groups 1 and 2 are overlapping, so some records would belong to both.

Do you have any suggestions on how to display such a summary?

Thanks a lot!
Irene

Comment: Could you be a more detailed about the dataset & what data you wish to show in the summary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Running Totals with an evaluate formula to only total certain rows. Assuming you have an {asofdate} parameter and the {month} data field...

1. last 6 months

   datediff("m", {month}, {asofdate}) <= 6
2. this year (last 12 months)

   datediff("m", {month}, {asofdate}) <= 12
3. last year (12 to 24 months ago)

   datediff("m", {month}, {asofdate}) >= 13
   and datediff("m", {month}, {asofdate}) <= 24
4. total
   just use a sum